# Connect SQL Server with PHP: Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

Inside config\database.php below setting is changed from mysql to sqlsrv

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
```

In connection list added the below code.

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => 'Pankaj\SQLEXPRESS', 
    'database' => 'pankaj',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'pankaj',
    'prefix' => '',
]
```

Inside .env file below are the modifications for Sql Server

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=Pankaj\SQLEXPRESS

DB_DATABASE=Pankaj
DB_USERNAME=sa
DB_PASSWORD=pankaj
```

**Error Details**

> PDOException in Connector.php line 119: could not find driver

Comment: Check if your driver is out of date

Comment: Seems fairly obvious, you don't have the `sqlsrv` driver installed.

Answer (score 0):

edit your `php.ini` file look up for this line:

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

remove the leading `;` then restart your server

Comment: There is no such line in ini file.

Comment: then add it among other extension files :)